# In Scala, how do I keep track of running totals without using var?

Tags: scala

For example, suppose I wish to read in fat, carbs and protein and wish to print the running total of each variable.  An imperative style would look like the following:

```
var totalFat = 0.0
var totalCarbs = 0.0
var totalProtein = 0.0
var lineNumber = 0

for (lineData <- allData) {
    totalFat += lineData...
    totalCarbs += lineData...
    totalProtein += lineData...
    lineNumber += 1

    printCSV(lineNumber, totalFat, totalCarbs, totalProtein)

}
```

How would I write the above using only vals?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `scanLeft`.

```
val zs = allData.scanLeft((0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)) {  case(r, c) =>
  val lineNr = r._1 + 1
  val fat = r._2 + c...
  val carbs = r._3 + c...
  val protein = r._4 + c...
  (lineNr, fat, carbs, protein)
}

zs foreach Function.tupled(printCSV)
```

Answer (score 3):

Recursion. Pass the sums from previous row to a function that will add them to values from current row, print them to CSV and pass them to itself...

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your data with `map` and get the total result with `sum`:

```
val total = allData map { ... } sum
```

With `scanLeft` you get the particular sums of each step:

```
val steps = allData.scanLeft(0) { case (sum,lineData) => sum+lineData}
val result = steps.last
```

If you want to create several new values in one iteration step I would prefer a class which hold the values:

```
case class X(i: Int, str: String)
object X {
  def empty = X(0, "")
}
(1 to 10).scanLeft(X.empty) { case (sum, data) => X(sum.i+data, sum.str+data) }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a jump to the left,
and then a fold to the right /:

```
class Data (val a: Int, val b: Int, val c: Int) 
val list = List (new Data (3, 4, 5), new Data (4, 2, 3), 
                 new Data (0, 6, 2), new Data (2, 4, 8)) 
val res = (new Data (0, 0, 0) /: list) 
  ((acc, x) => new Data (acc.a + x.a, acc.b + x.b, acc.c + x.c))
```